# Moq - Is it possible to setup a mock without using It.IsAny

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I use Moq all the time for unit tests.  Sometimes though I am mocking methods that have a lot of parameters.

Imagine a method like this:

```
public class WorkClient {

public void DoSomething(string itemName, 
   int itemCount, 
   ServiceClientCredential cred, 
   CancellationToken = default(CancellationToken){}
}
```

When I go to setup a mock, I end up having to do quite a lot of `It.IsAny<T>()`.  I normally make one mocked instance per each test so I don't care about matching params.

But my mocks still look like this

```
var newMockClient = new Mock<WorkClient>();
newMockClient.Setup(x => x.DoSomething(
   It.IsAny<string>(), 
   It.IsAny<int>(),
   It.IsAny<ServiceClientCredential(),
   It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
   .Returns(blah);
```

I would love to be able to just lazily instead use a LazySetup if it exists, like this.

```
newMockClient.Setup(x=>x.DoSomething()).Returns(blah);
```

Is there any lazy mode like this?

Comment: No I do not believe this is possible. `Moq` set up requires you to either pass a specific value or some variation of `It.Is()` or `It.IsAny()`

Comment: Please check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/7Pass/1c6b329e85ca29071f42). With that you can write semi-lazy setup like: `SetupIgnoreArgs(x => x.DoSomething(null, null, null, null, null).Returns(blah)`. I'm not sure it works with value types but I think it worths to give it a try

Comment: [Someone has pushed the idea even further](https://gist.github.com/christothes/7d57db1d16c96669ecd0218ab056a422)

Comment: @PeterCsala if you post this link and a sample usage as an answer, I would accept it.  It's perfect for the purposes I need so you should get credit for sharing it :)

Comment: @FoxDeploy Consider it done and thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Based on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/christothes/7d57db1d16c96669ecd0218ab056a422) you can create an overload for `SetupDefaultArgs` which works well with `void` return type.  You will need to add a reference to `Moq.Language.Flow` and `System.Linq.Expressions;`

```
public static ISetup<T> SetupDefaultArgs<T>(this Mock<T> mock, string methodName)
    where T : class
{
    var method = typeof(T).GetMethod(methodName);
    if (method == null)
        throw new ArgumentException($"No method named '{methodName}' exists on type '{typeof(T).Name}'");
            
    var instance = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "m");
    var callExp = Expression.Call(instance, method, method.GetParameters().Select(p => GenerateItIsAny(p.ParameterType)));
    var exp = Expression.Lambda<Action<T>>(callExp, instance);
    return mock.Setup(exp);
}

//helper method for above
private static MethodCallExpression GenerateItIsAny(Type T)
    {
        var ItIsAnyT = typeof(It)
            .GetMethod("IsAny")
            .MakeGenericMethod(T);
        return Expression.Call(ItIsAnyT);
    }
```

So, in your case the usage would look something like this:

```
public interface IWorkClient
{
    void DoSomething(string itemName, int itemCount,
        ServiceClientCredential cred,
        CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken));
}
```

```
var mock = new Mock<IWorkClient>();
mock.SetupDefaultArgs(nameof(IWorkClient.DoSomething));
```

To make sure that it has been called you can do the following:

```
//Arrange
var mock = new Mock<IWorkClient>();
mock.SetupDefaultArgs(nameof(IWorkClient.DoSomething))
    .Callback(() => Console.WriteLine("DoSomething has been called"));

var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

//Act       
mock.Object.DoSomething("1", 2, null, cts.Token);

//Assert
mock.Verify(client => client.DoSomething("1", 2, null, cts.Token), Times.Once);
```

Comment: @FoxDeploy Thanks for the edit, I forgot to copy that.