# Moq: Can I verify a method call without having to write "It.IsAny<type>()" for each parameter?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am writing Unit Tests in C# and Moq.

In order to verify that a method in a mocked class was not called at all, I am currently writing

```
// Assert
_connectorMock.Verify(x => x
            .MethodName(It.IsAny<Guid>(), It.IsAny<Guid>(), It.IsAny<string>(),
                It.IsAny<DataSchema>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Never);
```

This is not a real problem but it can get a bit messy and I was wondering if there is a shorter way to write this when verifying that a method was not called at all, i.e. every single parameter can be 'any'.

Comment: No there is no easier verify setup. It would be a problem with an overload of 'MethodName' with the same amount of parameter. The parameters are part of the method signature and relevant to find the proper method. The correct way would be to make the Mock strict. Anything called that has not been setup will fail then and no need to do such a verify then.

Comment: @Ralf
I see, I wasn't considering overloads. I will have a look into strict Mocks then (haven't done that before but it might be a good idea in general).
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose that your `_connectorMock` is a mock of the following `IConnector` interface

```
public interface IConnector
{
    void MethodName(Guid a, Guid b, string c, DataSchema d, CancellationToken e);
}
```

Then based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69723909/moq-is-it-possible-to-setup-a-mock-without-using-it-isany/70567658#70567658) you can define `Setup` and `Verify` calls
where the `It.IsAny`s are auto-generated

```
public static class MoqExtensions
{
    public static ISetup<T> SetupDefaultArgs<T>(this Mock<T> mock, string methodName) where T : class
        => mock.Setup(GenerateExpression<T>(methodName));

    public static void VerifyDefaultArgs<T>(this Mock<T> mock, string methodName, Times times)where T : class
        => mock.Verify(GenerateExpression<T>(methodName), times);  

    private static Expression<Action<T>> GenerateExpression<T>(string methodName)
    {
        var method = typeof(T).GetMethod(methodName)
            ?? throw new ArgumentException($"No method named '{methodName}' exists on type '{typeof(T).Name}'");

        var instance = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "m");
        var parameters = method.GetParameters().Select(p => GenerateItIsAny(p.ParameterType));
        var callExp = Expression.Call(instance, method, parameters);
        return Expression.Lambda<Action<T>>(callExp, instance);
    }

    private static MethodCallExpression GenerateItIsAny(Type T)
    {
        var ItIsAnyT = typeof(It)
            .GetMethod("IsAny")
            .MakeGenericMethod(T);
        return Expression.Call(ItIsAnyT);
    }
}
```

---

Here are some samples which shows you how can you use it

```
[Fact]
public void TestWhereMethodNameIsNotCalled()
{
    var _connectorMock = new Mock<IConnector>();
    _connectorMock.VerifyDefaultArgs(nameof(IConnector.MethodName), Times.Never());
}
```

[image: never called]

```
[Fact]
public void TestWhereMethodNameIsCalled()
{
    var _connectorMock = new Mock<IConnector>();
    _connectorMock.Object.MethodName(Guid.Empty, Guid.Empty, string.Empty, null, CancellationToken.None);
    _connectorMock.VerifyDefaultArgs(nameof(IConnector.MethodName), Times.Never());
}
```

[image: it has been called once]

Changing the `.Never()` to `.Once()` would change the result of the test case

[image: called once]